# How can I factorise this union of intersections of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I rewrite
$$
F = F_1 \cup \bigcup_{i=2}^{n \geq2} \left( 
F_i \cap \bigcap_{j=1}^{i-1} S_j
\right)
$$
without explicitly writing $F_1$?

Assume
\begin{align}
F_i \cap S_i &= \emptyset \\
\bigcup_{i=1}^n F_i \cup S_i &\subset \mathbb{R}^m.
\end{align}

For example, if $n=3$, then
$$
F = (F_1) \cup (F_2 \cap S_1) \cup (F_3 \cap S_1 \cap S_2).
$$

Comment: What space are you working on? are there relations between $F_i$ and $S_i$?

Comment: @macton, I'm working on $\mathbb{R}^m$. One relation is that $F_i \cap S_i = \emptyset$. Another is $\bigcup_{i \in n} F_i \cup S_i \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, i.e. it doesn't constitute of partition of $\mathbb{R^m}$.

Comment: You need to get rid of the $\ge 2$ in the upper limit on the union: that’s an external condition on $n$ that has no place in the union notation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, how should it be expressed then?

Comment: @ChristopherIliffeSprague: In a separate statement, something like this: Let $S_0=X$; then for $n\ge 2$ we have $$F=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\left(F_i\cap\bigcap_{j=0}^{i-1}S_j\right)\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a whole space called $X$, let's say, then define
$$
S_0 = X
$$
then clearly
$$
F_1 = F_1 \bigcap S_0
$$
and
$$
F_i \cap \bigcap_{j=1}^{i-1} S_j =F_i \cap \bigcap_{j=1}^{i-1} S_j \bigcap S_0 =  F_i \cap \bigcap_{j=0}^{i-1} S_j 
$$
so we can rewrite it as
$$F = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n \geq2} \left( 
F_i \cap \bigcap_{j=0}^{i-1} S_j
\right)$$
well it's a little bit cheating by introducing new variable but it works.

Comment: Thank you. This is out of the scope, but, should $S_0 = X$ be changed to $S_0 := X$, or perhaps $S_0 \triangleq X$?

Comment: @ChristopherIliffeSprague It's a personal preference. For me I've explicitly said "define" before that line, so it should be not that confusing. I use $:=$ only when I want to emphasis that definition.